# Asp.net Lock/Freeze Multi Row Gridview Headers

Tags: asp.net, gridview, header, freeze, multirow

I've been giving the task of freezing the headers on my Gridview. The Gridview must also be scrollable. I have accomplished the scrolling feature. I can't get the lock header feature. I've tried various solutions including css styles and JQuery plugins but nothing seems to be working. I think the biggest is that my Gridview has a multi row header. I define one row header in the aspx, then I created the second row header in the Gridview row data bound event. Any useful solutions?

Code Below

aspx

```
<div style="height: 95%; overflow-y: auto;">
                    <asp:GridView ID="markdownGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BackColor="White" RowStyle-Height="15" HeaderStyle-Height="20" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="small" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Calibri" RowStyle-Font-Names="Calibri" RowStyle-Font-Size="13px" BorderWidth="0" OnRowDataBound="markdownGrid_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="false" OnPageIndexChanging="markdownGrid_PageIndexChanging" GridLines="Both" >
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#E5F2FF" CssClass="rowHeight" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Row Header" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Stores Clearance Actual"
                                HeaderText="Clearance Actual" DataFormatString="{0:##,###,##0}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Stores Clearance Estimate" HeaderText="Clearance Estimate" DataFormatString="{0:##,###,##0}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Stores Clearance Total" HeaderText="Clearance Total" DataFormatString="{0:##,###,##0}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Stores POS Actual" HeaderText="POS Actual" ItemStyle-Width="4%" DataFormatString="{0:##,###,##0}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Stores MD Total" HeaderText="MD Total" ItemStyle-Width="4%" DataFormatString="{0:##,###,##0}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Stores Next Month Clearance Estimate" ItemStyle-Width="4%"
                                HeaderText="Next Month Clearance Estimate" DataFormatString="{0:##,###,##0}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Stores blank" ItemStyle-Width="0.5%" ItemStyle-BackColor="#F8F8F8" ItemStyle-BorderStyle="None" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="None" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#F8F8F8" />

                            <asp:BoundField DataField="COM Clearance Actual"
                                HeaderText="Clearance Actual" DataFormatString="{0:##,###,##0}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="COM Clearance Estimate" HeaderText="Clearance Estimate" DataFormatString="{0:##,###,##0}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="COM Clearance Total" HeaderText="Clearance Total" DataFormatString="{0:##,###,##0}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="COM POS Actual" HeaderText="POS Actual" ItemStyle-Width="4%" DataFormatString="{0:##,###,##0}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="COM MD Total" HeaderText="MD Total" ItemStyle-Width="4%" DataFormatString="{0:##,###,##0}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="COM Next Month Clearance Estimate" ItemStyle-Width="4%"
                                HeaderText="Next Month Clearance Estimate" DataFormatString="{0:##,###,##0}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="COM blank" ItemStyle-Width="0.5%" ItemStyle-BackColor="#F8F8F8" ItemStyle-BorderStyle="None" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="None" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#F8F8F8" />

                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Company Clearance Actual"
                                HeaderText="Clearance Actual" DataFormatString="{0:##,###,##0}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Company Clearance Estimate" HeaderText="Clearance Estimate" DataFormatString="{0:##,###,##0}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Company Clearance Total" HeaderText="Clearance Total" DataFormatString="{0:##,###,##0}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Company POS Actual" HeaderText="POS Actual" ItemStyle-Width="4%" DataFormatString="{0:##,###,##0}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Company Other Actual" HeaderText="Other-MDA" ItemStyle-Width="5%" DataFormatString="{0:##,###,##0}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Company MD Total" HeaderText="MD Total" ItemStyle-Width="4%" DataFormatString="{0:##,###,##0}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Company LY Clearance" HeaderText="LY Clearance EOW" DataFormatString="{0:##,###,##0}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Company Next Month Clearance Estimate" ItemStyle-Width="4%" HeaderText="Next Month Clearance Estimate" DataFormatString="{0:##,###,##0}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
```

code behind

```
protected void markupGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            if (dateSelection.Text != null)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].Text = dateSelection.Text;
            }

            GridViewRow headerow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header,
                                                      DataControlRowState.Insert);
            TableCell headercell = new TableCell()
            {
                // First blank cell                    
                Text = "PTD",
                ForeColor = Color.Red,
                HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center,
                BorderWidth = 1,
                BorderColor = Color.Black,
                CssClass = "gridSectionHeaders"
            };
            headerow.Cells.Add(headercell);

            headercell = new TableCell()
            {
                // TOTAL SELLING LOCATIONS header
                ColumnSpan = 2,
                Text = "TOTAL SELLING LOCATIONS",
                HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center,
                BorderWidth = 1,
                CssClass = "gridSectionHeaders"
            };
            headerow.Cells.Add(headercell);

            headercell = new TableCell()
            {
                // Second blank cell
                BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F8F8F8"),
                BorderWidth = 0
            };
            headerow.Cells.Add(headercell);

            headercell = new TableCell()
            {
                // COM header
                Text = "COM",
                ColumnSpan = 2,
                HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center,
                BorderWidth = 1,
                CssClass = "gridSectionHeaders"
            };
            headerow.Cells.Add(headercell);

            headercell = new TableCell()
            {
                // Last blank cell
                BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F8F8F8"),
                BorderWidth = 0
            };
            headerow.Cells.Add(headercell);

            headercell = new TableCell()
            {
                // TOTAL header
                ColumnSpan = 3,
                Text = "TOTAL",
                HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center,
                BorderWidth = 1,
                CssClass = "gridSectionHeaders"
            };

            headerow.Cells.Add(headercell);
            headercell.Height = 20;
            markupGrid.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, headerow);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [this](http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/Demo/Advanced.aspx#HeaderColumnMerge2).

Here is how I use it in my application and it works without any issues. Refer my others answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487694/gridview-with-fixed-header-and-full-page-width-grid/25494816#25494816) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438835/floating-gridview-header/25452213#25452213) on SO for the similar problem

```
<script type="text/javascript"      src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gridviewScroll.min.js"></script>
<link href="GridviewScroll.css" rel="stylesheet" />

function pageLoad(sender, args) {
   gridviewScroll ();
 }

 function gridviewScroll() {
    gridView1 = $('#GridView1').gridviewScroll({
       width: 915,
       height: 449,
       railcolor: "#F0F0F0",
       barcolor: "#CDCDCD",
       barhovercolor: "#606060",
       bgcolor: "#F0F0F0",
       freezesize: 5,
       arrowsize: 30,
       varrowtopimg: "../../../images/arrowvt.png",
       varrowbottomimg: "../../../images/arrowvb.png",
       harrowleftimg: "../../../images/arrowhl.png",
       harrowrightimg: "../../../images/arrowhr.png",
       headerrowcount: 1,
       onScrollVertical: function (delta) {
       // store the scroll offset outside of this function in a hidden field and restore if you want to maintain vertical scroll position
       },
      onScrollHorizontal: function (delta) {
        //store the scroll offset outside of this function in a hidden field and restore if you want to maintain horizontal scroll position
      }
    });
  }
```

And the screen print on how the frozen grid header looks in my application
[image]

Comment: I tried to use the gridviewScroll before. It only supports freezing/locking 1 header row. I need to freeze 2 maybe 3 header rows

Comment: @Jmunndi You have an option to do that. Change the value for the property `headerrowcount: 2` or `headerrowcount: 3` within the `$('#GridView1').gridviewScroll({ .. ` function depending on your need.

Comment: I played with it more and it's starting to come together. My issue was that I was using a div to handle my scrolling instead of the plugin. I still prefer that option because I'm having trouble with setting the height and width. I cannot use fixed pixel values, I have to use percentages. When I set the width to 100%, my grid shoots pass the screen and horizontal scrolling enables. I do not want that. Vertical scrolling is okay but horizontal scrolling is not okay. Any suggestions for setting the grid's height and width in percentages?