# GridView with Frozen Headers and PagerTemplate

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to setup a GridView with fixed headers. I can do this, however, once I add my PagerTemplate to the top of the page, my headers are no longer fixed in place. If I omit the PagerTemplate or put it at the bottom instead, everything works as expected. Below is my code with the PagerTemplate at the top how I want it, so the headers are not fixed for vertical scrolling. Any help is appreciated:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />                             
    <style type="text/css">
        .GridViewStyle
        {    
            background-color:White; 
        }

        .GridViewHeaderStyle
        {
            color:White;
            background-color:Black;
        }
    </style>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function CreateGridHeader(DataDiv, GridView1, HeaderDiv) {
            var DataDivObj = document.getElementById(DataDiv);
            var DataGridObj = document.getElementById(GridView1);
            var HeaderDivObj = document.getElementById(HeaderDiv);

            //********* Creating new table which contains the header row ***********
            var HeadertableObj = HeaderDivObj.appendChild(document.createElement('table'));

            DataDivObj.style.paddingTop = '0px';
            var DataDivWidth = DataDivObj.clientWidth;
            DataDivObj.style.width = '5000px';

            //********** Setting the style of Header Div as per the Data Div ************
            HeaderDivObj.className = DataDivObj.className;
            HeaderDivObj.style.cssText = DataDivObj.style.cssText;
            //**** Making the Header Div scrollable. *****
            HeaderDivObj.style.overflow = 'auto';
            //*** Hiding the horizontal scroll bar of Header Div ****
            HeaderDivObj.style.overflowX = 'hidden';
            //**** Hiding the vertical scroll bar of Header Div **** 
            HeaderDivObj.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
            HeaderDivObj.style.height = DataGridObj.rows[0].clientHeight + 'px';
            //**** Removing any border between Header Div and Data Div ****
            HeaderDivObj.style.borderBottomWidth = '0px';

            //********** Setting the style of Header Table as per the GridView ************
            HeadertableObj.className = DataGridObj.className;
            //**** Setting the Headertable css text as per the GridView css text 
            HeadertableObj.style.cssText = DataGridObj.style.cssText;
            HeadertableObj.border = '1px';
            HeadertableObj.rules = 'all';
            HeadertableObj.cellPadding = DataGridObj.cellPadding;
            HeadertableObj.cellSpacing = DataGridObj.cellSpacing;

            //********** Creating the new header row **********
            var Row = HeadertableObj.insertRow(0);
            Row.className = DataGridObj.rows[0].className;
            Row.style.cssText = DataGridObj.rows[0].style.cssText;
            Row.style.fontWeight = 'bold';

            //******** This loop will create each header cell *********
            for (var iCntr = 0; iCntr < DataGridObj.rows[0].cells.length; iCntr++) {
                var spanTag = Row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
                spanTag.innerHTML = DataGridObj.rows[0].cells[iCntr].innerHTML;
                var width = 0;
                //****** Setting the width of Header Cell **********
                if (spanTag.clientWidth > DataGridObj.rows[1].cells[iCntr].clientWidth) {
                    width = spanTag.clientWidth;
                }
                else {
                    width = DataGridObj.rows[1].cells[iCntr].clientWidth;
                }
                if (iCntr <= DataGridObj.rows[0].cells.length - 2) {
                    spanTag.style.width = width + 'px';
                }
                else {
                    spanTag.style.width = width + 20 + 'px';
                }
                DataGridObj.rows[1].cells[iCntr].style.width = width + 'px';
            }
            var tableWidth = DataGridObj.clientWidth;
            //********* Hidding the original header of GridView *******
            DataGridObj.rows[0].style.display = 'none';
            //********* Setting the same width of all the componets **********
            HeaderDivObj.style.width = DataDivWidth + 'px';
            DataDivObj.style.width = DataDivWidth + 'px';
            DataGridObj.style.width = tableWidth + 'px';
            HeadertableObj.style.width = tableWidth + 20 + 'px';
            return false;
        }

        function Onscrollfnction() {
            var div = document.getElementById('DataDiv');
            var div2 = document.getElementById('HeaderDiv');
            //****** Scrolling HeaderDiv along with DataDiv ******
            div2.scrollLeft = div.scrollLeft;
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="HeaderDiv">
        </div>
        <div id="DataDiv" style="overflow:auto; width:100%; height:500px;" onscroll="Onscrollfnction();">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDS1" BackColor="White" 
                OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" AllowPaging="True" 
                AllowSorting="True" PageSize="1000" OnPreRender="GridView_PreRender" 
                CssClass="GridViewStyle" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                <PagerSettings Position="Top" />
                <PagerTemplate>
                    <div>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="PagingDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="PagingDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" height="30px" />
                    </div>
                </PagerTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeaderStyle" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDS1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TTN-CSS-01ConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
Looking into this a little more, it looks like the issue is that when the table is constructed, if there is PagerTemplate used on Top then the new table generated by the javascript is using that as the top row so if I'm not mistaken, the paging row is the one frozen (even though I already have it as a fixed position). I'm just not sure how to go about resolving this. After loading the pages and viewing the source here's what I'm seeing.

PagerTemplate on Top (not working)

```
    <div>
    <div id="HeaderDiv">
    </div>
    <div id="DataDiv" style="overflow:auto; width: 100%; height: 500px;" onscroll="Onscrollfnction();">
        <div>
        <table class="GridViewStyle" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="GridView1" style="background-color:White;border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="16">
                    <div class="pages">
                        <select name="GridView1$ctl01$PagingDropDownList" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'GridView1$ctl01$PagingDropDownList\',\'\')', 0)" id="GridView1_ctl01_PagingDropDownList" style="height:30px;">
                            <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="color:White;background-color:#DF1E37;">
                <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Sort$Col1')" style="color:White;">Col1</a>
```

PagerTemplate on Bottom or off (working)

```
    <div>
    <div id="HeaderDiv">
    </div>
    <div id="DataDiv" style="overflow:auto; width: 100%; height: 500px;" onscroll="Onscrollfnction();">
        <div>
            <table class="GridViewStyle" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ReportsGridView" style="background-color:White;border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tr style="color:White;background-color:#DF1E37;">
                    <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ReportsGridView','Sort$Col1')" style="color:White;">Col1</a></th>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to place the PagerTemplate outside of GridView without writing a lot of code so what I ended up doing is going with a  [GridViewScroll with jQuery](http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/) instead of the javascript I was attempting to use. With the jQuery option I can specify how many rows should be frozen, so selecting 2 freezes the PagerTemplate as well as my header row.

Hers a SO link where someone explains how they implemented it, which is similar to what I did in this case.

[Asp.net Lock/Freeze Multi Row Gridview Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748379/asp-net-lock-freeze-multi-row-gridview-headers)